# Current path in PHP on Windows (standalone CLI)

Tags: windows, path, php

I was trying to get path current path in PHP. I tried looking though `phpinfo();`, but I haven't found any interesting values which could be used to get path to my script. There is no nice values which I used on Linux, like `$_SERVER["PWD"]`.

Now I'm wondering how I'm supposed to find current path. Maybe some function will work... I really have no idea. Because I don't want to hardcode path to script.

Comment: Try using [`__FILE__`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear whether you mean the current working directory, or the path to the current script. For the working directory, see @Taze's answer.

For the current *script*, the [`__FILE__`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php) magic constant will give you the full filesystem path to the current file.

Note that  these constants take "current file" literally: If you include a file and call `__FILE__` there, it will show the *included file*'s path.

Answer (score 1):

The [`getcwd()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php) method will return the current working directory on success.

```
<?php
    echo getcwd() . "\n";
?>
```